# Angular4 error message shows code which differs from the code that's supposed to be serving

Tags: json, angular, typescript, syntax, webpack

I'm writing an app to go into a website, which is intended to calculate simplex algorithms. At the moment I am attempting to create functionality whereby the user can enter the number of coefficients and constraints, name these whatever they wish, and have the app spawn the relevant number and type of UI elements relative to the user's input. Here's what appears to be the relevant portion of the code (*app.component.ts*):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

[...]

export class UIComponent {
  id: 1;
  name: string;
  value: number;
  type: string;
}

//* Mock data */
const UICOMPONENTS: UIComponent[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'coefficient1', value: 4, type: '1dslide' },
  { id: 2, name: 'constraint1', value: 2, type: '2dslide' },
  { id: 3, name: 'min_max', value: 0, type: 'switch' },
  { id: 4, name: 'profit', value: 100, type: 'num_output' }
];

[...]

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'SimutronX';
  uicomponents = UICOMPONENTS;
  [...]
}
```

This produces an error on screen saying:

```
Failed to compile.

/root/simutronx/simutron-app/src/app/app.component.ts (18,49): ',' expected.
```

Which relates to this line:

```
{ id: 2, name: 'constraint1', value: 2, type: '2dslide' },
```

Specifically the digit `2` in `2dslide`. The error message (it's extremely long so I won't reproduce it all) also includes:

```
./src/app/app.component.ts
Module parse failed: /root/simutronx/simutron-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js!/root/simutronx/simutron-app/src/app/app.component.ts Unexpected token (22:85)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var UICOMPONENTS = [
|     { id: 1, name: 'coefficient1', value: 4, type: '1dslide' },
|     { id: 2, name: 'constraint1, value: 2, type: ', 2: dslide, ' },: { id: 3, name: 'min_max', value: 0, type: 'switch' }, },
|     { id: 4, name: 'profit', value: 100, type: 'num_output' }
| ];
```

Which is particularly confusing since, as you can see, that's not how I wrote the code. What's going on here?

Comment: `type` is a contextual keyword in Typescript. Maybe you could try with another property name ? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2536

Comment: Ah. I did wonder if type might be a reserved word, but then became confused because the code listed didn't seem to match what I wrote. I'll try to work out another appropriate name and see if that fixes the problem...

Comment: it works as expected with `tsc` against all targets. Probably a bug in @ngtools/webpack which does some very dangerous code transformations.

Comment: @hiper2d both are valid in that position.

Comment: I changed `type` to `widget` but it's still doing basically the same thing (exact reference has changed because of the additional letters in `widget` but everything else is the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in UIComponent type :

```
export class UIComponent {
  id: number; //HERE
  name: string;
  value: number;
  type: string;
}
```

Here a plunker :http://plnkr.co/edit/e6GrylSWznwbYD9VpK2C